# SQL query to see differentiated value

Tags: mysql, sql

I take a daily snapshot of the user-login logs(logged in or not) at every 4am which is categorised by each regions with the sum of the daily users.
However, I want to create a SQL query to see the differentiated values(possibly with percentage) with the day before so that I can see which region has increased or decreased their users.
I know I can hardcode this but is there any elegant ways to do that in rather simple SQL query?

Comment: "I know I can hardcode this" : Post the 'Hardcoded' part it will help us understand what your doing and how to simplify it.

Comment: You need to join yesterday's report to today's report.  Can you show the table structure?

Comment: mysql> select date,region,count(id) from snapshot_logs group by region,date;
+------------+--------+----------+
| date       | region |count(id) |
+------------+--------+----------+
| 2012-07-21 |      1 |   169631 |
| 2012-07-22 |      1 |   168545 |
| 2012-07-23 |      1 |   168051 |
| 2012-07-24 |      1 |   982888 |
| 2012-07-25 |      1 |   982043 |
| 2012-07-21 |      2 |   200733 |
| 2012-07-22 |      2 |   198709 |
| 2012-07-23 |      2 |   197006 |
| 2012-07-24 |      2 |   194539 |
| 2012-07-25 |      2 |   190998 |
| 2012-07-21 |      3 |   199011 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
There are two ways to do this:
First Way:
1. Create a table in your database
    CREATE TABLE user_logs (id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT, daily_number varchar(1000), current_percentage varchar(30), date datetime)
2. Run the script to get the number of users for that day
    INSERT INTO user_logs (daily_number) VALUES ($daily_value)
3. Create function to compare the latest two DB rows, then insert percentage into (numberOfRows-1)


Second Way:
1. Create a log of the user records in a txt file
2. In the log, append each number seperated by comma
3. Create function to compare the last two values in log and take the average of the two
```